# segmentation fault in this pointers program in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, initialization

I keep getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) message whenever I try to run this C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 200, *p, *q, *r;
    p,r = &i;
    q = p;
    *q = *p + 1;
    printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
    printf("*r = %d\n", *r);
    return 0;
}
```

It didn't have any `r`s at first but I had to add `r`s as an alias to `i` and then Add print statements to output the dereferenced values of `q` and `r`.

Comment: `p,r = &i;` what do you think this line does?

Comment: [What does the comma operator , do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c)

Answer (score 6):

In your code

```
p,r = &i;
```

does not assign `p`, it leaves `p` uninitialized. Next, the very moment you dereference `p` (and `q` also, as it was assigned with the value of `p`) you hit 
 [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're dereferencing invalid memory.

You need to use

```
p = r = &i;
```

Compile your code with proper warnings enabled and, with your code, you should see something similar to

> *warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]*
>
> ```
>  p,r = &i;
>   ^
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
p = &i;
r = &i;
```

instead of

```
p,r = &i;
```

Uninitialized pointer is bad.

Comment: `Uninitialized pointer is undefined behavior.` without proper context, this is rubbish. How about `int *p; p = NULL;`. `p` was unitialized, was not it?

Comment: especially an uninitialized pointer is NOT undefined behavior. Dereferencing one is.

Answer (score 0):

`//I write that as an answer because i still don't have 50 reputation`

**1:** I didn't understand what do you want that the program will do. the use of q and r is useless.

**2:** `p,r=&i;` is not a good command. use `p=r=&i` or `p=&i; r=&i;` or 
`p=&i; r=p;`

Comment: the second point is not true `p,r=&i;`is a valid command, it just doesn't do anything with p. Plus what you said is already covered by sourav (an hour before) so you don't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

i have made the correction in your code and it is working fine please have look into it.

```
`#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 200, *p, *q, *r;
    p = &i;
    r = &i;    
    q = p;
    *q = *p + 1;
    printf("*p = %d\n", *p);
    printf("*r = %d\n", *r);
    return 0;
}`
```